# В Android studio пишет что ничего нету в component tree и design, как исправить?

Tags: android, android-studio, sdk

У меня при создании layout и в папке "menu" в проекте,component tree и design почему то пусто написано "Nothing to show", хотя код написан (ошибок в коде нету), как это исправить? и с чем это может быть связанно?